# Projectiles In Gamemaker Studio 2 Not Moving

Tags: game-maker, gml, projectile, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

My gun's begin step code:

```
if (global.night == true) {

    image_angle = point_direction(x, y, mouse_x, mouse_y);
    image_index = 1;
    alarm[0] = 0.5 * room_speed;
    firingdelay -= 1;

    if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)) && (firingdelay < 0) {

        firingdelay = 10;
        with (instance_create_layer(Revolver.x+12, Revolver.y, "Bullets", Bullet)) {
            direction = Revolver.image_angle;
            speed = 25;
            image_angle = direction;
        } 
    }
}
```

It creates the bullets, but they don't move. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have physics enabled in a room, the regular speed and direction variables will not work. Do you have physics enabled? The code looks fine.